Multi window dock preview missing
I recently messed a bit with GNOME on my other laptop (22.04.4) and I don't have this preview when having multiple windows open.
How the system behaves:
When I click on multiple open windows (the icon in the Dock), the active window rotates. So at first, it activates the first one, a second click, the second one, etc.
What I expect the system to behave:
When I click on the icon in the Dock (when multiple windows are open) I expect to see what is shown in the screenshot below. So I can easily navigate to the respective window. Sometimes I have multiple windows and rotating by clicking is not efficient.

How it started:
I installed the Evolution email client and after some testing, I removed it (sudo apt remove). I ended up with terminal access only (after reboot) so I installed gnome and gnome-panel again. Right after that it stopped behaving like I wanted.
I have another laptop with a fresh install of 24.04 and it works as expected.
Any idea how to turn this feature on again?

I believe by reinstalling the gnome and gnome-panel, you have changed the "Click action" for the Ubuntu Dock. You can change it back through the following steps:

Open Gnome Extensions or Extension Manager. Then under the System extensions, select Ubuntu Dock.
Click on the three dots or the Settings Icon and then select the Behaviour section.
Now on Click Action, select the option "Focus or App Spread". After that, you will get your desired actions.



omg .. thank you so much !!!! this is exactly it :) savior!!!!
